# Are sinking and supplying current both limited to same level in an opamp (LM741?)

Tags: operational-amplifier

I know that an LM741 opamp can only supply up to around 20mA of current. However I don't know whether its sinking capability is also restricted or not.

p.s : I refer sinking when current flows into opamps output. I am not sure that thing is sinking, but I assume so.

Comment: What have you found in the datasheet?

Comment: Um, OK, so let's assume it's unlimited: so you can, without hurting that device, sink 100 A into the IC? That sounds unlikely, even if I had never heard of what an opamp is or what an LM741 looks like.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I know that it can't be 100 A, but maybe it is 200mA for example.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm741.pdf nothing in here.

Comment: Read the data sheet, like  Elliot Alderson said.

Comment: @SteveSh I have shared the link above, I could not find it.

Comment: @muyustan ok, where did you find the 20 mA in that, then? Also, you're still using the LM741, which you've been pointed out before, is the worst possible opamp. If you have an opamp that needs to sink a specific current, go to a distributor's website and list all opamps that fullfil your criteria. Nearly every opamp you can buy these days is better than the LM751, maybe aside from the OP8x.

Comment: @MarcusMüller it says "output short circuit current" around 20-25 mA, but I don't know if this is only valid when current flows out of opamp or for both in and out.

Comment: muyustan - That can be inferred from the Output Voltage Swing numbers in table 6.5.

Comment: There's more information in the u741 data sheet.  It has a typical curve of Maximum Output Voltage vs Load Resistance.  But you need to be cautious using typical numbers or curves to design with.

Comment: The **short circuit** current rating does not tell you how much current the op amp can source or sink when it is operating as an amplifier. Under short circuit conditions the output voltage is always 0V, by definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

*Figure 1. Internals of the ancient 741 opamp. Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_amplifier#Internal_circuitry_of_741-type_op-amp).*

From the internal schematic of the 741 op-amp it should be clear that the output can source current from the \$ V_{S+} \$ rail via Q14 or sink current to the \$ V_{S-} \$ rail via Q20. The datasheet quotes maximum output current as 25 mA and doesn't differentiate between sourcing and sinking current. From this and the schematic showing a push-pull output stage it would be safe to assume that its sourcing and sinking capabilities are the same.

Comment: thanks for being such kind and helpful.

Comment: Note that the 25mA value is the **short circuit** output current so the output voltage is always 0V. If you want the op amp to function as an actual amplifier then the available output current is much less.